# How do I load categorical variable with pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm getting the following error when loading data into a dataframe, and automatic conversion to categorical variables.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filename,
                 header=0,
                 index_col=False,
                 usecols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                 dtype={'col1': int,
                        'col2': 'category',
                        'col3': float})
```

> TypeError: data type "category" not understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently it's not implemented, but you can use the following workaround:

```
dtype={'col1': int,
       'col2': pd.CategoricalDtype(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']),
       'col3': float}
```

[here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10153) is still **open** feature request

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is convert it to a categorical after the fact, especially considering that you may not know all of the valid categories until after you read the file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filename, usecols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df['col3'] = df.col3.astype('category')
```